# How do I prevent OS X from immediately trying to mount unlocked drive / prompt for password?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, encryption, hfs+

Due to a hard disconnect of my encrypted external hard drive, it seems my HFS+ partition has become corrupted. Every time I unlock my hard drive, OS X tries to mount it silently in the background and then hard ejects the drive, such that OS X is not recognizing it whatsoever in `diskutil list` and I have to turn off/turn back on my hard drive bay.

I run:

```
$ diskutil cs unlockVolume 7DB6AE16-158B-45A4-B1F7-7791B650E552
```

To unlock the drive, which makes the GUI password prompt disappear, but then when I try to run:

```
$ sudo fsck_hfs -fryS /dev/disk3
```

I get:

** /dev/rdisk3 (NO WRITE)
Can't open /dev/rdisk3: Resource busy

I was able to get one successful `fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk3` to run, and here are the results:

```
$ diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk3
Started file system verification on disk3 BLUE1
Verifying storage system
Checking volume
disk2s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk2s2: Scan for Disk Labels
Logical Volume Group 4A47A942-A97F-4A96-B46A-4B405B598C02 on 1 device
disk2s2: Scan for Metadata Volume
Logical Volume Group has a 24 MB Metadata Volume with double redundancy
Start scanning metadata for a valid checkpoint
Load and verify Segment Headers
Load and verify Checkpoint Payload
Load and verify Transaction Segment
Incorporate 0 newer non-checkpoint transactions
Load and verify Virtual Address Table
Load and verify Segment Usage Table
Load and verify Metadata Superblock
Load and verify Logical Volumes B-Trees
Logical Volume Group contains 1 Logical Volume
Load and verify 64E4D5E6-74B6-482E-8F57-9C079C22702D
Load and verify 7DB6AE16-158B-45A4-B1F7-7791B650E552
Load and verify Freespace Summary
Load and verify Block Accounting
Load and verify Live Virtual Addresses
Newest transaction commit checkpoint is valid
Load and verify Segment Cleaning
The volume 4A47A942-A97F-4A96-B46A-4B405B598C02 appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Verifying file system
File system check exit code is 8
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 8: Exec format error
```

However, I want to try `S` scanning the drive for badblocks (in case that's the actual reason it can't mount), and `r` <s>because then it spells fryS</s> because if one of the logical volume b-tree is what's corrupted then it would need to be rebuilt, or maybe t wouldn't have gotten so far in the fsck. Really this is just a guess at this point, I'm trying anything.

Comment: *"...maybe I wouldn't have gotten so far in the fsck..."*: I don't see any successful file system check! *"Storage system check exit code is 0"* is a successful LVG/PV/LV metadata check (disk2s2)  which isn't really related to disk3's HFS+ file system.

Comment: That's why I want to rebuild the b-tree catalog. It doesn't seem like it's getting all the way through that step.